# cron job for a list of jobs each 15 minutes after another

Tags: cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I want to run a couple of cron jobs each after another with a 15-minute gap, like this:

```
run task1
...15 minutes later
run task2
...15 minutes later
run task3
```

and so on. What is the best way to do this with cron?

Comment: Do you intend to run task1 again after completing taskN everytime (a cycle) or is it just a simple run from task1 to taskN? What is the total number of tasks?

Comment: @FalakDhruve Yes, in a cycle one after another, the total number at the moment is about 50 and a subject to change (+- 5)

Comment: Do you want to start task2 15 minutes after task1 completes, or 15 minutes after task1 starts (assuming that each task takes a non-trival time to run)?